# Make a Mapbox RMAnnotation display its callout programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, markers

I'm making an iOS app (using Swift) that has a map in the Mapbox iOS SDK. I've gotten to the point of displaying several markers on the map. Now, I want the user to be able to select a marker from the list, panning to that marker (easy), which also makes the marker's callout bubble appear automatically without the user having to touch it (not so easy).

It's this last task I'm having trouble with. While I've found the RMMarker class's showLabel() method, I can't seem to directly access a RMAnnotation's associated RMMarker object, so I'm not sure where or how to call this method.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the `showLabel()` API — this is not the callout in use, but rather a text label that's possible directly on the annotation.

You probably want `-[RMMapView selectAnnotation:animated:]` with a `NO` in the `animated` argument.